# Could not load xDebug .dll in xampp

Tags: xampp, xdebug

Trying for a while but could not fixed the php_xdebug.dll load issue.

```
Php Version: 7.0.9
xDebug Version: PHP 7.0 VC14 (64 bit) 
  file: php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll
```

I have copied the .dll file in ext directory and edited the php.ini directory accordingly

```
php.ini configuration:
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.01"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_log="C:\xampp\logs"
```

After restarting the apache, If I check the php --ini then getting load error

```
C:\xampp\php>php --ini
Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the .dll file is not in the "ext" folder. Check the "zend_ext" folder.